# How can I use GroupBy in Laravel without turning things off

Tags: php, sql, laravel

The following code isn't working:

```
\App\Models\News::groupBy("category")->orderBy('pubDate', 'DESC')->limit(21)->get();
```

It says id isn't in the group by ....
I tried using DB::table and even raw query (DB::raw) but result was the same.
I googled and somebody said it's because of the changes in newer version of MySQL.
So I got the generated query by the following:

```
$res =\App\Models\News::groupBy("category")->orderBy('pubDate', 'DESC')->limit(21)->toSql(); 
     echo "<div style='display:none'>\n   ".print_r($res,true)." \n</div>";
```

And It gives me this:

```
  select * from `news` group by `category` order by `pubDate` desc limit 21
```

I copied and pasted it to PhpMyAdmin and it works fine.

Another one said you should disable strict mode in config/database.php. But what if I don't want to change any configs?
I don't think strict mode being enabled means I can't use groupBy anymore. Right?

If I'm right just tell how should I make the above code work.

Please don't give me links to the docs. They're hard for me to understand.

All I want is a simplest sql query which has a "groupBy" statment and works without turning something off.

ThankYou

***Edit***

Table structure for table news

|Column|Type|Null|Default

|//**id**//|int(11)|No|

|title|varchar(200)|No|

|description|varchar(500)|No|

|link|varchar(300)|No|

|source|varchar(50)|No|

|category|varchar(20)|Yes|NULL

|**pubDate**|varchar(40)|No|

|ts|datetime|No|current_timestamp()

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images). [mcve].

Comment: select column depends on group by column. all the columns you select have to be in group by or inside aggregate function e.g. max(column), count(column) etc. Since you select *, it breaks the above rule.

Comment: @ Anurat Chapanond I have several columns. Should I groupBy all of them for no reason?

Comment: Try this `$q = \App\Models\News::select("*", DB::raw("MAX(pubDate) as pubDate")->groupBy('category')->orderBy('pubDate', 'desc')->limit(21)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 DB::select("SELECT * FROM `news` GROUP BY `category` ORDER BY `pubDate` DES limit 21")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
News::select("*")->orderBy('pubDate', 'desc')->groupBy("category")->limit(21)->get();
```

**FYI**

In some cases, I had to use the below line before executing the query.

```
DB::statement("set sql_mode='' ");
```